# Get URL and redirect before page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

So, i have an interesting situation. I've been working on re-organizing a directory on a website. I updated old files there's about 100 of them, they are in a new location. The old files have been taken down.

The problem I have is there are probably hundreds of people that have bookmarks directly to the URL of the old files. (e.i. "wahwah.com/subSite/pdfs/something.pdf") these files are 5 years old so they need to find the new ones anyways.

So instead of having a page for each individual file, Can I have something in the directory that used to house the files to watch for that URL and redirect to the new page?

It would watch for "wahwah.com/subSite/pdfs.." and redirect. Or maybe something in the main directory of this subSite to watch for the URL to have the /pdf path in it.

I know I can grab URLs in java script but that doesn't help me unless I can do what I stated above. I'm not sure how if at all I could do it in .NET. our servers support .NET because most of our site apps were made with it but I don't deal with those. I cannot use PHP, the servers don't use it.

I'm hoping JavaScript will be able to do it somehow, but it's something i've never tried before so just thinking about it i'm not sure I can. I'm not much for using JS libraries so Im not sure what is out there i've been searching a bit though.

I found Grunt but i'm not entirely sure how it works just yet. Just looking around maybe the file filter or matchBase. or some of the Global patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to server, your best option is to set up redirect in there on wahwah.com/subSite/pdfs/ directory.
How to do this depends on if you're on IIS or unix.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net, 301 redirect is fairly efficient.

```
if (HttpContext.Contains("http://old.aspx"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("http://www.new.aspx");
    }
```

Or in page load you can write:

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location","http://new.aspx");
```

Comment: where would I put something like this? In a separate file in the directory containing the sub site or the old files directory?

Comment: @MGHandy Since you are using ASP.net, I'm assuming you are using IIS. The first one should be placed in global.asax, particularly in Application_BeginRequest or Application_Start. In the second one, each must be in the old web pages' on load event.

Comment: There's about 100 old files. I need another way to redirect all of those paths to the new page.